# Simple java chat program doesn't work on Mac

Tags: java, macos, serversocket

I have made a simple java chat program that will have 1 server and 1 client. It works fine on windows, it can chat with each other within LAN.
But when I try it on Mac computer, it doesn't work. In the server program, if it works properly, it should freeze when I press the start button, and wait for client to join. But in Mac, it does nothing when I press start button. The program doesn't freeze, it's like clicking on a non-coded button. The client in Mac cannot join the server too (server hosted in Windows).

On Windows: Start server --> freeze(wait for client) --> Client joined --> able to chat

On Mac: Start server --> not freeze, like click on normal button --> Client clicked join --> nothing happens

In the Start Server button:

```
private void startsvbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        server = new ServerSocket(7430);
        client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client request accepted: "+client.getOutputStream());
        dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        ReceiveMessage serverThread = new ReceiveMessage(dis,textarea);
        serverThread.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No client available");
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer without more info/code ... Have you tried debugging? either with some IDE or by using log/sysout

Comment: I develop it from my computer (windows) and compile it. So I dont know where to debug because it works fine on all Windows computer.

Comment: You can try putting log statements at points where you suspect ... if you put up the rest of the code, someone on SO might be able to help

Comment: which JDK are you using on your Mac?

Comment: maybe it's the latest, because this mac has never installed java before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking only IOException, as per doc there could be other exceptions. Catch all and print stacktrace.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--

```
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it says "Permission denied".

Comment: Permission denied usually happens if it's a privileged port < 1024. But that does not seem to be the case here. Try a few things : 1. Check if any other process is using 7430 by using netstat command 2. Try changing to some other ports 3. Try running java as root user 4. search SO for permission denied error for OS X there must be others who have faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because your button doesn't freeze I would say that the problem is an exception is being thrown, hence your ActionListener returning virtually immediately.

Check your log file to see if your log message `System.out.println("No client available");` is there.  Also at the very least modify this code to output the stack trace, as I would bet that you cannot bind to the port specified here:

```
server = new ServerSocket(7430);
```